# How I can root Asus Padfone T00C?

Tags: rooting, asus-padfone-t00c

How can I root my Asus Padfone T00C?

Comment: Have you tried any of the standard rooting methods, like [towelroot](https://towelroot.com)?

Comment: Not knowing the Android version running on the device, it's hard to give any recommendations. As eldarerathis suggested, Towelroot is a good one to start with. For more, take a look at our [rooting index], which names a couple of them – often along with the information on which Android versions it's supposed to work.